# Regex bypass three dots only

Tags: python, regex

I have this string:

```
z='Certainly. I like apples... Really? By all means. Yes!'
```

I want to capture the `.`, `?` and `!` but not the `...` substring, so the desired output should be:

```
['.', '?', '.', '!']
```

This is what I've got:

```
>>> re.findall('(?<!\.)[\.?!]', z)
['.', '.', '?', '.', '!']
```

This regex is also capturing the first dot of the `...` substring. But if I run:

```
>>> re.findall('(?<!\.{2})[\.?!]', z)
['.', '.', '.', '?', '.', '!']
```

Quite the opposite of what I expected, and I don't understand why since I'm asking the lookahead to not match if two dots preceed (attempting to use quantifier any operator `+?*{1,2}` yields an error because look-behind requires fixed-width pattern).

I'm misunderstanding something because I would expect that adding a second `\.` to the lookahead would yield my desired output.

I would appreciate any suggestions and brief explanations (couldn't find anything exactly like what I'm asking).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses  **negative lookbehind and lookahead**,

```
>>> import re
>>> z='Certainly. I like apples... Really? By all means. Yes!'
>>> z
'Certainly. I like apples... Really? By all means. Yes!'
>>> m = re.findall(r'(?<!\.)[.?!](?!\.)', z)
>>> m
['.', '?', '.', '!']
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zN2vG6/8)

The above regex matches the dots `.` or `?` or `!` which are not preceded by a  dot and not followed by a dot.

Comment: Yes this works thanks... Why does making it a raw string work?

Comment: To avoid escaping by \

Comment: Wouldn't it then be looking for the `\.` literal though? Why is it read as `..` instead of `\.` ?

Comment: @xv70 because you're forgetting Python's parse of the string before Regex's parse of the string. Python parses `\.` as a literal `.`, then regex parses `.` as "any character." Python parses `r"\."` as a literal `\.` and regex parses that `\.` as a literal `.`

Comment: @xv70 N.B. [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) on Regex RE: raw string notation

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility:

```
pat = re.compile(r"\.\.\.|([.?!])")
matches = filter(None, pat.findall(z))
```

This works by matching the literal `...` and consuming that string before we have a chance to put it into a capturing group (on the other side of the "OR" pipe (`|`)), then filtering the results to remove all the `''` (which is what `findall` uses when it finds a match with an empty capturing group).

This has been called by some as [The Best Regex Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)